# Django model field with function

Tags: django, django-models

It it possible ? I want compare two fields and return score to bet_score field.

```
class Tabela(models.Model):
    score1= models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    score2 = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=3)
    bet_score= models.IntegerField(defaults=bet_score())


    def bet_score(self):
        if (self.score1> self.score2 ):
            return 1
        elif (self.score1== self.score2 ):
            return 0
        else:
            return 2
```

Comment: Of course not automagically, but why do you need a field `bet_score` then? Isn't the function already doing what you need?

Comment: Now I create first model, I wish that bet_score fields automatically fill depends on score1 and score2. Maybe i should change place to call bet_score function ?

Comment: If you there's no need to add a field, you can just use a function. Add the dcorator `@property` would make it look like field: `tablea.bet_score` instead of `tablea.bet_score()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store this kind of thing on a model, I think your best option would be to override the save method:

```
class Tabela(models.Model):
    score1= models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    score2 = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=3)
    bet_score= models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.score1 > self.score2 ):
            self.bet_score = 1
        elif (self.score1 == self.score2 ):
            self.bet_score = 0
        else:
            self.bet_score = 2
        super(Tabela, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) for more info.